# Prove that $H\times K \cong K\times H$

Tags: group-theory, alternative-proof

According to the book:

> Let $G$ be the internal direct product of subgroups $H$ and $K$. 
>   Then $G$ is isomorphic to $H\times K$.

From that it results $H\times K \cong K\times H$. Is there any 'direct' proof for $H\times K \cong K\times H$ i.e. without using the mentioned theorem?

Comment: Make a bijection between them.

Comment: Do you realize that if $G$ is the internal direct product of $H$ and $K$, then $H$ and $K$ commute and have trivial intersection, whence $H\times K\cong HK=G=KH\cong K\times H$?

Comment: @Batominovski - yes I know. But how it helps with the question, since in direct product elements are 'separate' in $(h,k)$?

Comment: So, with internal direct product approach, you can also show $H\times K\cong K\times H$.  Now, instead, consider $\tilde{G}=H\times K$.  Then, the subgroup $\tilde{H}=H\times \left\{1_K\right\}$ and $\tilde{K}=\left\{1_H\right\}\times K$ are isomorphic to $H$ and $K$, respectively.  Thus, $\tilde{G}$ is the internal direct product of $\tilde{H}$ and $\tilde{K}$, and therefore ….

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's an extremely obvious bijective homomorphism to use between the two, namely

$$\phi(h,k)=(k,h)$$

Also I'll add that you may not know what the significance of a bijective homomorphism is, or what a homomorphism even is. If it'll help you for me to expand on the terms I've used, just leave a comment letting me know and I'll give a more thorough explanation.

Comment: I proved one-to-one and onto. But I don't know how to prove it preserves isomorphism, i.e. I can't form $\phi(k) o \phi(h)=\phi (k.h)$ or something like that.

Comment: You should show that $\phi((h_1,k_1)(h_2,k_2))=\phi(h_1,k_1)\phi(h_2,k_2)$

Comment: And why homomorphism not isomorphism? Thank you

Comment: An isomorphism is a one-to-one, onto homomorphism. So you've already shown it's one-to-one and onto; then to show it's an isomorphism you just need to show it's a homomorphism.

Comment: $\phi((h_1,k_1)(h_2,k_2))=(k_1,h_1)(k_2,h_2)=\phi(h_1,k_1)\phi(h_2,k_2)$. Thanks a lot.

Comment: What you've done isn't completely correct. To be considered proper you should have $\phi((h_1,k_1)(h_2,k_2))=\phi(h_1h_2,k_1k_2)=(k_1k_2,h_1h_2)=(k_1,h_1)(k_2,h_2)=\phi(h_1,k_1)\phi(h_2,k_2)$

Comment: $(k_1k_2,h_1h_2)=(k_1,h_1)(k_2,h_2)‌​$ is correct but it can be decomposed to some other pair-elements also which makes the last step not unique.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you're asking with your question. The reason your solution was wrong is because we have defined this map only for a single element of $H\times K$. Therefore you can't just apply it to the product of two elements the way you did. You have to multiply them into a single element of $H\times K$ before you can apply the mapping.

Comment: I meant that if $k_1k_2=k_1'k_2'$ and $h_1h_2=h_1'h_2$, but still doesn't change the result since still $\phi(h_1,k_1)\phi(h_2,k_2)=\phi(h_1',k_1')\phi(h_2',k_2')$  (?)